# Qt QTreeWidgetItem text contents vs widget item vs data

Tags: c++, qt

upon construction of QTreeWidgetItem you can pass a list of strings, so when you insert it in a table(QTreeWidget), you get the strings listed on a row. However, from the methods of the table you can also call setItemWidget and set a text widget or any sort of widget to be in that row, but it seems incompatible with having a string list, since the widget is drawn over the strings. There is also a setData method for the QTreeWidgetItem, which sets some data that can be retreived, but isn't visible to the user. Is there a cookie-cutter way of properly using all three data storage methods? Are they even compatible or must I stick to only one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Constructor of QTreeWidgetItem is convenient to immediately list the desired content.

When inserting a custom widget in a cell, you need to change its `autoFillBackground`property to `true`, so that it is not transparent. See the [QTreewidget::setItemWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#setItemWidget) description:

> The given widget's autoFillBackground property must be set to true,
>   otherwise the widget's background will be transparent, showing both
>   the model data and the tree widget item.

`QTreeWidgetItem::setData` can be used when already having an item and you want to change one of its contents.

Of course you can combine any of these methods, but it is hard to say, which approach is best without knowing your use case. Just one more hint: If you just need a plain stupid representation of data that does not change, using QTreeWidget is fine. But if your displayed data can change, e.g. objects get deleted, added, changed in various locations of your code, a QTreeView with a custom data model might be a better choice.